# numbers x such that the sum of the divisors is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Hello I am reading "The Theory of Numbers, by Robert D. Carmichael" and stuck in an exercise problem,

Find numbers x such that the sum of the divisors of x is a perfect square.

I know sum of divisors of a x=$p_1^{\alpha_1}.p_2^{\alpha_2}....p_i^{\alpha_i}$ is

Sum of divisors = $\prod{\frac{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}}$

But couldn't proceed further on how resolve the product in to X2

It will be helpful if someone supply some hints

Comment: See the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006532) entry.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006532) doesn't seem to have a general formula or any details about if there are infinitely many such numbers. They are using brute force I guess.

Comment: OEIS does not have it because it is not known. This is also an answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks